# Solve $y'(x)=\frac{y^2(x)/x^2}{1+y(x)/x}$ via substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

**Assignment:** Find the solution of the following ODE:

$$y'(x)=\frac{y^2(x)/x^2}{1+y(x)/x}.$$

---

I've tried the substitution $RHS=:v(x,y)$, as well as a few others but doesn't seem to work in simplifying the differential equation, since, for example, the former results in $$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{2y\frac{dy}{dx}(x+xy)-y^2((x+xy)\frac{dy}{dx})}{x^2(1+y)^2}$$ which doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: How about trying $v(x,y)=\frac{y(x)}{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=vx$. Then you get $$v+xv'=\frac{v^2}{1+v}.$$I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you, I now get that $v'(x)=-\frac{v(x)}{x}$ but I'm actually looking for something that has a term $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in order to solve this. Do you maybe know how I should proceed?

Comment: Notice the new equation he has made from this substitution is separable, and much easier to solve. You can solve this for ${v}$, and since ${v=y/x}$ that will allow you to rearrange for ${y=x\times v}$ (you will now have $v$ known)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Set $z(x)=\frac{y(x)}{x}$. Then your equation becomes
$$xz'(x)+z(x)=\frac{z(x)^2}{1+z(x)}\iff z'(x)(1+z(x))=-\frac{1}{x}$$